# graylog not getting cents 7.1 syslog messages using the rsyslogd service

Tags: centos, rsyslog

Good morning!  I'm playing with Graylog today and everything is working well on Ubuntu, but the two CentOS 7.1 servers I've attempted to attach to it are acting strange.  I've been keeping notes as I've gone along and have pasted them below.  Thank you for taking the time to read through this!

When forwarding to rsyslog the logs are written to the remotes /var/log files
When forwarding to Graylog the service will not send the logs, but if rsyslog is started by `sudo rsyslogd` instead of the syslog service it will work

Here is the output of `ps aux | grep sysl` for each process:
  From the service:

> [user]$ ps aux | grep sysl
>
> root     12362  0.0  0.1 311228  2804 ?        Ssl  10:19   0:00 /usr/sbin/rsyslogd -n
>
> user+ 12369  0.0  0.0 112640   928 pts/0    S+   10:19   0:00 grep --color=auto sysl

From `sudo rsyslogd`:

> [user]$ ps aux | grep sysl
>
> root     12320  0.0  0.1 313300  2336 ?        Ssl  10:18   0:00 rsyslogd
>
> user+ 12354  0.0  0.0 112640   932 pts/0    S+   10:18   0:00 grep --color=auto sysl

The application should be the same as noted here:

> [user]$ which rsyslogd
>
> /usr/sbin/rsyslogd

The only difference then is the use of the `-n` flag.

Contents of the rsyslog systemd service file:

> [Unit]
>
> Description=System Logging Service
>
> ;Requires=syslog.socket
>
> [Service]
>
> Type=notify
>
> EnvironmentFile=-/etc/sysconfig/rsyslog
>
> ExecStart=/usr/sbin/rsyslogd -n $SYSLOGD_OPTIONS
>
> StandardOutput=null
>
> [Install]
>
> WantedBy=multi-user.target
>
> ;Alias=syslog.service

$SYSLOGD_OPTIONS is "" according to /etc/sysconfig/rsyslog

Running `sudo /usr/sbin/rsyslogd -n` sends messages, but locks the terminal session (CTRL-C will not get out, have to close the tmux pane and reconnect, but rsyslogd will stay running)

Removing `-n $SYSLOGD_OPTIONS` from the service will cause the service to not startup (it crashes, I did run `sudo systemctl daemon-reload`)

Comment: I do not see an edit button, but I would like to note autocorrect butchered the title a bit, it should be CentOS not Cents :)

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out.  I was being dumb.  SELinux does not allow syslog to send logs over a non-standard port, which is what I was trying to do.  Installing `policycoreutils-python` and running `sudo semanage port -a -t syslogd_port_t -p tcp 5514` fixed it :)